# trick to match photoshop pixel size and css render pixel size

Tags: css, size, pixel, photoshop

Checked different sites but no clear answer. Every time I get a new design in photoshop I try to match the pixel sizes into my css code. The browser then renders the size completely different than what I see in the photoshop file. I always get all the files with a 72pp resolution.

Is there a trick to match the pixel size of the photoshop to be the same as the CSS pixel size  once rendered?

As a visual example...

Same typography, google font typography in this case.

Both have the value of 18px

Photoshop:
[image]

CSS render:
[image]

Comment: If they are the same element, how come they have different text?

Comment: This is not answer but helpful chrome plugin - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi?hl=en helps you to match HTML with PSD also as far as I know your HTML should be almost replica of designs so why do you need extra efforts to match pixels?

Comment: @PravinVaichal I'm sometimes too perfectionist, maybe there was a trick to get the exact value be the same. But I'm beginning to thin that does not exist.

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero Sounds great so if you get any useful answer or way Please post for others as well :) Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, mate. I translate perfectly all my psd into css with no problem.

Work ALWAYS with 72dpi images and be sure at preferences > Units & Rules > Units to mark both "rulers" and "type" as pixels

Comment: Menendez So your pixel value in the psd matches your css value? They do not look slightly bigger?

Comment: Images always are identical. I'm afraid I can't help you about fonts as I never use px as size unit. Always em and I make the font size as close as possible visually and using some of the chrome nice apps like "page ruler".

Comment: Btw, when you create a new psd document, you can always use the "web" preset. Probably it would be helpfull.